# JavaFX TreeTableView - Prevent selection of certain TreeItems

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-8, treetableview

I have looked at a couple of questions here, but I can't seem to find anything related to disabling selection of rows for TreeTableViews in particular in JavaFX.

The closest related questions I have come across are all related to TreeViews:

1. [How to make certain JavaFX TreeView nodes non-selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999674/how-to-make-certain-javafx-treeview-nodes-non-selectable/31059296)
2. [TreeView - Certain TreeItems are not allowed to be selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267157/treeview-certain-treeitems-are-not-allowed-to-be-selected)

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31275673/475044) given in question 2 where a custom selection-model is used that extends from `MultipleSelectionModel` seems to be the most promising. However, the problem with TreeTableViews are that they use a custom `TreeTableViewSelectionModel` that itself extends from `TableSelectionModel`.

If you do a naive implementation where you just forward the calls to a wrapped `TreeTableViewSelectionModel` and provide filtering in the `select()` and `selectAndClear()` methods as follows:

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel;

public class FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> extends TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> {

    private final TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> selectionModel;
    private final TreeItemSelectionFilter<S> filter;

    public FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel(
            TreeTableView<S> treeTableView,
            TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> selectionModel,
            TreeItemSelectionFilter<S> filter) {
        super(treeTableView);
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeTablePosition<S, ?>> getSelectedCells() {
        return this.selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        return this.selectionModel.isSelected(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        TreeItem<S> treeItem = treeTableView.getTreeItem(row);
        if (this.filter.isSelectable(treeItem)) {
            this.selectionModel.select(row);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        TreeItem<S> treeItem = treeTableView.getTreeItem(row);

        // If the specified row is selectable, we forward clear-and-select
        // call to the delegate selection-model.
        if (this.filter.isSelectable(treeItem)) {
            this.selectionModel.clearAndSelect(row);
        }
        // Else, we just do a normal clear-selection call.
        else {
            this.selectionModel.clearSelection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        this.selectionModel.clearSelection(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLeftCell() {
        this.selectionModel.selectLeftCell();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectRightCell() {
        this.selectionModel.selectRightCell();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAboveCell() {
        this.selectionModel.selectAboveCell();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectBelowCell() {
        this.selectionModel.selectBelowCell();
    }
}
```

where you filter with this interface:

```
public interface TreeItemSelectionFilter<S> {

    public boolean isSelectable(TreeItem<S> treeItem);
}
```

Your TreeTableView's selection will not work correctly as you'll see that the selected rows are not properly highlighted as in this example where I selected the first row:

[image]

Am I missing something in the way it needs to be implemented, or is there another way to provide selection filtering for TreeTableViews?

Answer (score 0):

I pieced together a class by looking at the internals of `TreeTableViewArrayListSelectionModel`. As the `TreeTableViewSelectionModel` class itself has state, a lot of the superclass methods needed to be overridden to provide implementations that forwarded either to the internal selection-model or to one of the other methods that itself forwards to the internal selection-model. The implementation of this class is as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.OptionalInt;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView.*;

public class FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> extends TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> {

    private final TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> selectionModel;
    private final TreeItemSelectionFilter<S> selectionFilter;

    public FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel(
            TreeTableView<S> treeTableView,
            TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> selectionModel,
            TreeItemSelectionFilter<S> selectionFilter) {
        super(treeTableView);
        this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
        this.selectionFilter = selectionFilter;
        cellSelectionEnabledProperty().bindBidirectional(selectionModel.cellSelectionEnabledProperty());
        selectionModeProperty().bindBidirectional(selectionModel.selectionModeProperty());
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        return this.selectionModel.getSelectedIndices();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<S>> getSelectedItems() {
        return this.selectionModel.getSelectedItems();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeTablePosition<S, ?>> getSelectedCells() {
        return this.selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int index) {
        return this.selectionModel.isSelected(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        return this.selectionModel.isSelected(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.selectionModel.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public TreeItem<S> getModelItem(int index) {
        return this.selectionModel.getModelItem(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void focus(int row) {
        this.selectionModel.focus(row);
    }

    @Override
    public int getFocusedIndex() {
        return this.selectionModel.getFocusedIndex();
    }

    private TreeTablePosition<S,?> getFocusedCell() {
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        TreeTableViewFocusModel<S> focusModel = treeTableView.getFocusModel();
        return (focusModel == null) ? 
            new TreeTablePosition<>(treeTableView, -1, null) :
            focusModel.getFocusedCell();
    }

    private TreeTableColumn<S,?> getTableColumn(int pos) {
        return getTreeTableView().getVisibleLeafColumn(pos);
    }

    // Gets a table column to the left or right of the current one, given an offset.
    private TreeTableColumn<S,?> getTableColumn(TreeTableColumn<S,?> column, int offset) {
        int columnIndex = getTreeTableView().getVisibleLeafIndex(column);
        int newColumnIndex = columnIndex + offset;
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        return treeTableView.getVisibleLeafColumn(newColumnIndex);
    }

    private int getRowCount() {
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        return treeTableView.getExpandedItemCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int row) {
        select(row, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        // If the row is -1, we need to clear the selection.
        if (row == -1) {
            this.selectionModel.clearSelection();
        } else if (row >= 0 && row < getRowCount()) {
            // If the tree-item at the specified row-index is selectable, we
            // forward select call to the internal selection-model.
            TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
            TreeItem<S> treeItem = treeTableView.getTreeItem(row);
            if (this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeItem)) {
                this.selectionModel.select(row, column);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void select(TreeItem<S> treeItem) {
        if (treeItem == null) {
            // If the provided tree-item is null, and we are in single-selection
            // mode we need to clear the selection.
            if (getSelectionMode() == SelectionMode.SINGLE) {
                this.selectionModel.clearSelection();
            }
            // Else, we just forward to the internal selection-model so that
            // the selected-index can be set to -1, and the selected-item
            // can be set to null.
            else {
                this.selectionModel.select(null);
            }
        } else if (this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeItem)) {
            this.selectionModel.select(treeItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectIndices(int row, int ... rows) {
        // If we have no trailing rows, we forward to normal row-selection.
        if (rows == null || rows.length == 0) {
            select(row);
            return;
        }

        // Filter rows so that we only end up with those rows whose corresponding
        // tree-items are selectable.
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        int[] filteredRows = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(row), Arrays.stream(rows)).filter(rowToCheck -> {
            TreeItem<S> treeItem = treeTableView.getTreeItem(rowToCheck);
            return (treeItem != null) && selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeItem);
        }).toArray();

        // If we have rows left, we proceed to forward to internal selection-model.
        if (filteredRows.length > 0) {
            int newRow = filteredRows[0];
            int[] newRows = Arrays.copyOfRange(filteredRows, 1, filteredRows.length);
            this.selectionModel.selectIndices(newRow, newRows);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectRange(int start, int end) {
        super.selectRange(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectRange(int minRow, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> minColumn, int maxRow, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> maxColumn) {
        super.selectRange(minRow, minColumn, maxRow, maxColumn);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int row) {
        clearAndSelect(row, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        // If the row is out-of-bounds we just clear and return.
        if (row < 0 || row >= getRowCount()) {
            clearSelection();
            return;
        }

        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        TreeItem<S> treeItem = treeTableView.getTreeItem(row);

        // If the tree-item at the specified row-index is selectable, we forward
        // clear-and-select call to the internal selection-model.
        if (this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeItem)) {
            this.selectionModel.clearAndSelect(row, column);
        }
        // Else, we just do a normal clear-selection call.
        else {
            this.selectionModel.clearSelection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {
        int rowCount = getRowCount();

        // If we are in single-selection mode, we exit prematurely as
        // we cannot select all rows.
        if (getSelectionMode() == SelectionMode.SINGLE) {
            return;
        }

        // If we only have a single row to select, we forward to the
        // row-index select-method.
        if (rowCount == 1) {
            select(0);
        }
        // Else, if we have more than one row available, we construct an array
        // of all the indices and forward to the selectIndices-method.
        else if (rowCount > 1) {
            int row = 0;
            int[] rows = IntStream.range(1, rowCount).toArray();
            selectIndices(row, rows);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int index) {
        this.selectionModel.clearSelection(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int row, TableColumnBase<TreeItem<S>, ?> column) {
        this.selectionModel.clearSelection(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection() {
        this.selectionModel.clearSelection();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectFirst() {
        // Find first selectable row in the tree-table by testing each tree-item
        // against our selection-filter.
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        OptionalInt firstRow = IntStream.range(0, getRowCount()).
            filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
            findFirst();

        TreeTablePosition<S,?> focusedCell = getFocusedCell();

        // If we managed to find a row, we forward to the appropriate internal
        // selection-model's select-method based on whether cell-seleciton is
        // enabled or not.
        firstRow.ifPresent(row -> {
            if (isCellSelectionEnabled()) {
                this.selectionModel.select(row, focusedCell.getTableColumn());
            } else {
                this.selectionModel.select(row);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLast() {
        // Find first selectable row (by iterating in reverse) in the tree-table
        // by testing each tree-item against our selection-filter.
        int rowCount = getRowCount();
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();
        OptionalInt lastRow = IntStream.iterate(rowCount - 1, i -> i - 1).
            limit(rowCount).
            filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
            findFirst();

        TreeTablePosition<S,?> focusedCell = getFocusedCell();

        // If we managed to find a row, we forward to the appropriate internal
        // selection-model's select-method based on whether cell-seleciton is
        // enabled or not.
        lastRow.ifPresent(row -> {
            if (isCellSelectionEnabled()) {
                this.selectionModel.select(row, focusedCell.getTableColumn());
            } else {
                this.selectionModel.select(row);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void selectPrevious() {
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();

        if (isCellSelectionEnabled()) {
            // In cell selection mode, we have to wrap around, going from
            // right-to-left, and then wrapping to the end of the previous line.
            TreeTablePosition<S,?> pos = getFocusedCell();

            // If we are not at the first column, we go to the previous column.
            if (pos.getColumn() - 1 >= 0) {
                this.selectionModel.select(pos.getRow(), getTableColumn(pos.getTableColumn(), -1));
            }
            // Else, we wrap to end of previous selectable row.
            else {
                // If we have nothing selected, wrap around to the last index.
                int startIndex = (pos.getRow() == -1) ? getRowCount() : pos.getRow();

                // Find previous selectable row.
                OptionalInt previousRow = IntStream.iterate(startIndex - 1, i -> i - 1).
                limit(startIndex).
                filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
                findFirst();

                // Last column index.
                int lastColumnIndex = getTreeTableView().getVisibleLeafColumns().size() - 1;

                // If we have a previous row, forward selection to internal selection-model.
                previousRow.ifPresent(row -> this.selectionModel.select(row, getTableColumn(lastColumnIndex)));
            }
        } else {
            // If we have nothing selected, wrap around to the last index.
            int startIndex = (getFocusedIndex() == -1) ? getRowCount() : getFocusedIndex();
            if (startIndex > 0) {
                OptionalInt previousRow = IntStream.iterate(startIndex - 1, i -> i - 1).
                    limit(startIndex).
                    filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
                    findFirst();
                previousRow.ifPresent(this.selectionModel::select);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectNext() {
        TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();

        if (isCellSelectionEnabled()) {
            // In cell selection mode, we have to wrap around, going from
            // left-to-right, and then wrapping to the start of the next line.
            TreeTablePosition<S,?> pos = getFocusedCell();

            // If we are not at the last column, then go to the next column.
            if (pos.getRow() != -1 && pos.getColumn() + 1 < getTreeTableView().getVisibleLeafColumns().size()) {
                this.selectionModel.select(pos.getRow(), getTableColumn(pos.getTableColumn(), 1));
            }
            // Else, wrap to start of next selectable row.
            else if (pos.getRow() < getRowCount() - 1) {
                // If we have nothing selected, starting at -1 will work out correctly
                // because we'll search from 0 onwards.
                int startIndex = pos.getRow();

                // Find next selectable row.
                OptionalInt nextItem = IntStream.range(startIndex + 1, getRowCount()).
                    filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
                    findFirst();

                // If we have a next row, forward selection to internal selection-model.
                nextItem.ifPresent(row -> this.selectionModel.select(row, getTableColumn(0)));
            }
        } else {
            // If we have nothing selected, starting at -1 will work out correctly
            // because we'll search from 0 onwards.
            int startIndex = getFocusedIndex();
            if (startIndex < getRowCount() - 1) {
                OptionalInt nextRow = IntStream.range(startIndex + 1, getRowCount()).
                    filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
                    findFirst();
                nextRow.ifPresent(this.selectionModel::select);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLeftCell() {
        if (!isCellSelectionEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        TreeTablePosition<S,?> pos = getFocusedCell();
        if (pos.getColumn() - 1 >= 0) {
            select(pos.getRow(), getTableColumn(pos.getTableColumn(), -1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectRightCell() {
        if (!isCellSelectionEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        TreeTablePosition<S,?> pos = getFocusedCell();
        if (pos.getColumn() + 1 < getTreeTableView().getVisibleLeafColumns().size()) {
            select(pos.getRow(), getTableColumn(pos.getTableColumn(), 1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAboveCell() {
        TreeTablePosition<S,?> pos = getFocusedCell();

        // If we have nothing selected, wrap around to the last row.
        if (pos.getRow() == -1) {
            selectLast();
        } else if (pos.getRow() > 0) {
            TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();

            // Find previous selectable row.
            OptionalInt previousRow = IntStream.iterate(pos.getRow() - 1, i -> i - 1).
                limit(pos.getRow()).
                filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
                findFirst();

            // If we have a previous row, forward selection to internal selection-model.
            previousRow.ifPresent(row -> this.selectionModel.select(row, pos.getTableColumn()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectBelowCell() {
        TreeTablePosition<S,?> pos = getFocusedCell();

        // If we have nothing selected, start at the first row.
        if (pos.getRow() == -1) {
            selectFirst();
        } else if (pos.getRow() < getRowCount() -1) {
            TreeTableView<S> treeTableView = getTreeTableView();

            // Find next selectable row.
            OptionalInt nextItem = IntStream.range(pos.getRow() + 1, getRowCount()).
                filter(row -> this.selectionFilter.isSelectable(treeTableView.getTreeItem(row))).
                findFirst();

            // If we have a next row, forward selection to internal selection-model.
            nextItem.ifPresent(row -> this.selectionModel.select(row, pos.getTableColumn()));
        }
    }
}
```

The `selectFirst()`, `selectLast()`, `selectNext()` and `selectPrevious()` methods were implemented by searching for the first TreeItem that satisfied the filter from an index in a specific direction. The corresponding row is then forwarded to the internal selection-model.

The `selectRange()` methods were just implemented by forwarding to their superclass counterparts that is actually implemented in `MultipleSelectionModel` (not sure if this is correct) as the implementation in `TreeTableViewArrayListSelectionModel` requires access to its internal `selectedCellsMap` data-structure that opens up a whole can of worms if we try to copy all of that functionality.

I also bind the `cellSelectionEnabledProperty` and the `selectionModeProperty` to the internal selection-model as this needs to reflect the state that the internal model was in when first created. This also allows us to change these properties for the internal selection-model and the updates will be reflected in the `FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel`.

To use the `FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel` you need to implement the  `TreeItemSelectionFilter` interface (as given in the question) and pass it as one of the constructor arguments for the `FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel` together with the TreeTableView and existing selection-model:

```
...
TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> selectionModel = treeTableView.getSelectionModel();
TreeItemSelectionFilter<S> treeItemFilter = MyCustomSelectionFilter<>();
FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> filteredSelectionModel = new FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel(treeTableView, selectionModel, treeItemFilter);
treeTableView.setSelectionModel(filteredSelectionModel);
...
```

I've uploaded the source-code of an example application [here](https://gist.github.com/wcmatthysen/754b8675b21c14fc46ed0925f53ad427) so that you can easily test the behavior of the `FilteredTreeTableViewSelectionModel` for yourself. Compare it with the default selection-model and see if you are satisfied with the behavior.